# find out number of days between end of each month and date of maximum value in r

Tags: r, date, max

I have a data frame where the first column is the date and the first row is the firms. The df is like this:

```
date            A        B       C       D
1/2/1998        0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1/5/1998        0.2     3.2     9.4     3.8
1/6/1998        2.1     2.5     1.7     0.9
1/7/1998        2.0     0.0     1.7     0.1
1/8/1998        12.7    3.7     5.3     1.1
1/9/1998        1.2     0.0     3.1     2.3
1/12/1998       2.1     0.0     0.0     1.4
```

When I find out maximum value for each month, I use the following code:

```
df1 <- aggregate(df[,-1],
                      by=list(Month=format(df$date,"%y-%m")),
                      FUN=max)
```

Now I want to create another data frame where I will find the number of days between max date to the end of that month. For example, if the maximum value comes on 20 April, the new variable would be 10. My desired output may like the following:

```
Month          A      B       C      D
1998-1        20     12       26    14
1998-2        10     14       4     3
1998-3        15     18       9     12
1998-4        12     20       27    12
1998-5        22     24       5     23
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. If the input is 20 February, why is the output 10?

Comment: input is not 20 of February. it is the date when the maximum return value comes. it may differ in the next month

Comment: You say "*For example, if the maximum value comes on 20 February, the new variable would be 10*". I don't understand why the new variable is 10 in this case. February has 28 or 29 days depending on the year, so it seems like the result should be 8 or 9, not 10. Is this just a mistake, or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: Your sample data frame is helpful, but would be more helpful if you showed your desired output for that input.

Comment: I have given sample output. @Gregor

Comment: sorry it is a mistake and I have changed it. @greogor

Comment: I still don't understand at all. Can you explain, based on your sample input, why `B` is `12` in the `1998-1` row? Why aren't there any 0s in your output - shouldn't the row with the maximum of the month be 0 days to the maximum? Why are there 5 rows of output for 7 rows of input? Is your `date` column in `m/d/y` or `d/m/y` format?

Comment: It is not possible to provide daily data of five months in the question. I just give an example of a few rows. for example, if maximum return comes on 21 January 1998 for that month for company A,  the number of days would be 10 on 1998-1 for company A.

Comment: Okay, but when you give an example, make the example output *actually correspond* to the example input. 2 rows from January and 3 rows from February, **with the expected output for that input,** would be less data than you shared, but do a better job illustrating the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example data:**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2018-02-10", "2018-02-15", 
                                  "2018-02-20", "2018-03-01", "2018-03-03")), 
                 V1 = runif(5), V2 = runif(5))
df1 <- aggregate(df[, -1],
                 by=list(Month=format(df$date,"%y-%m")),
                 FUN=max)
df1
  Month        V1        V2
1 18-02 0.6222994 0.6403106
2 18-03 0.8609154 0.6660838
```

**Max. date in each month:**

```
df2 <- tapply(1:nrow(df), format(df$date,"%y-%m"), 
              function(x) df[x, 1][apply(df[x, -1, drop = FALSE], 2, which.max)])
df2 <- data.frame(Month = names(df2), do.call(rbind, df2))
df2[, -1] <- lapply(df2[, -1], as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01")
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)
df2
      Month         V1         V2
18-02 18-02 2018-02-15 2018-02-10
18-03 18-03 2018-03-03 2018-03-01
```

**Diff. days to next month:**

```
library(lubridate)
df3 <- df2
df3[, -1] <- lapply(df3[, -1], function(x) days_in_month(x) - day(x) + 1)
df3
      Month V1 V2
18-02 18-02 14 19
18-03 18-03 29 31
```

Comment: thank you so much. each firm should have one max date for each month. if V1 is firm A, V2 is firm B, then each month they should have different max date.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your data structure, can you give a reproducible example?